# REST API for coinspot in C#

Tags: c#, api, json.net

I am doing a bit of research into building a program to use the Australian crypto trading platform Coinspot. I have used API's in the past but barley used "POST" method, Coinspots information and documentation is sooooooo poor (probs because they don't want you to use it) but i figured ill give it a whirl anyways.

Question:
How do you use a POST method if you do not know the order in which to send data? (is there a standard or is every API different).

i have an API key and a secret API key to send for authorisation but still get access denied.
Is there anyway you can use code to request an order or something like you do when you pull a json to string?

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.coinspot.com.au/api/ro/balances");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("key", APIKEY);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            request.GetResponse(); //THIS IS WHERE IT ERRORS WITH AUTHENTICATION
```

sorry if its a scrub question but i think im looking at this the right way, i am also using .NET library json newtonsoft so any information on this would be fantastic!!

Comment: Are you sure your API Key gives you access to the POST method? They may have secured the POST method so that you need a different key to call it - so no matter what you do, if your API Key doesn't have the necessary permission to call the POST method then it will never let you.

Comment: I've never seen a system that cared about the order of fields being POST'ed. Most of the time, the query parameters appear as a key-value hash on the server. In my experience, authentication errors sometimes happen due to missing headers, i.e. security tokens. Try searching for 'authentication' or 'token' in their API docs.

Comment: so when you create an API in your account settings it gives you 1 key and then you view a secret key once. and im guessing you use them both together? i think i am missing something but was really unsure as to order or something

Comment: @Getwrong It depends on how a particular entity defines their authentication system. It can be one key or a mix of a secret key. You would have to read their docs and then send the required key in the header.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core interpretation of the somewhat dated yet functional [CoinSpot node.js api client](https://www.npmjs.org/package/coinspot-api)

```
var nonce = Utility.GetEpochTime();
var postData = new { nonce };
var jsonMessage = postData.ToJson();
var hmac = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("CoinSpotSecret"));
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonMessage);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray)) {
    var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(stream).Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + String.Format("{0:x2}", e), s => s);
    var uri = new Uri("https://www.coinspot.com.au/api/ro/my/balances", UriKind.Absolute);
    var content = new StringContent(
                  jsonMessage,
                  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                  "application/json"
                  );

    content.Headers.Add("sign", hash);
    content.Headers.Add("key", "CoinSpotKey");
    
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```